# Compare text UILabel and change background

Tags: objective-c, for-loop, uilabel

I have created a for loop with values ranging from 18 to 30.
The label that the for loop gives me are these:

18 20 22 24 26 28 30

Once the for loop that returns the label, I wanted to compare the presence of a numeric value entered manually from those returned by the for loop through a simple "if statement"

Up to here it all works very well, my NSLog returns the correct answer based on the added value ...

What I would like to do is to find the numeric value as done so far and change the background color of the label or the label height containing the comparative number ...

Let me give an example:

if I enter the number 28 and is found, I would like that among all the label present, only the label that contains the value 28 would change color ..

I hope they managed to explain well, if I was not clear to ask me and I will try 'to explain the best

Can you help me ?

This is the code that I got so far

```
 NSMutableArray *container = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (_yValue = maxY; _yValue >=minY; _yValue -=2) {
    _yLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    _yLabel.frame = CGRectMake(xPadding, yPadding, 27, 27);
    _yLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)_yValue];
    _yLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    _yLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue" size:10];
    [self addSubview:_yLabel];
    yPadding += _yLabel.frame.size.height;

    [container addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInteger:_yValue]];
}


NSNumber *fetch = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:28];

if ([container containsObject:fetch]) {
    return NSLog(@"YES THIS IS 28");


} else {
    return NSLog(@"NO THIS IS NOT 28");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use tag of your `UILabel` with

```
_yLabel.tag = _yValue;
```

Then

```
if ([container containsObject:fetch]) {
     UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[self viewWithTag:[fetch integerValue]];
    label.textColor = [UIColor redColor];
    return NSLog(@"YES THIS IS 28");
}
```

Comment: i have an warning ... incompatible pointer to integer conversion assigning to nsinteger from nsstring

Comment: _yLabel.tag = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)_yValue];

Comment: This is correct :)         _yLabel.tag = _yValue ;
not [_yValue integerValue];